# Read email into a SQL database in ASP .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, screen-scraping, web-scraping, email

I read this post
[.net code to read email into a sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701512/net-code-to-read-email-into-a-sql-database) and I was wondering if there is a FREE way to do this.

I would like to store some emails on my database. Perhaps having them parsed first so that the URL of the links are stored in a different field in the database table.

Right now the emails are going to my Gmail. One way I'm thinking is that it may be possible to:

1. Find an email client which uses POP3 to connect to my Gmail
2. Retrieve and save my emails onto my local drive as Text files
3. Have a local .Net console/windows app run periodically to parse these text files to extract the data
4. Interface with an ASP .Net Web Service to forward the data and save it onto my production database.

Is this a good FREE method? Is there such an email client which saves email as text files on the local drive?

Comment: Please give some feedback on my answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using free Lumisoft POP3Client, or IMAPClient library.

http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Net/Help/html/4c15101c-f077-b8bf-84d7-7acae59394a4.htm

http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Net/Help/html/3a016d21-18f9-ba83-631f-05a1040fa345.htm

I've been using these in the production code and I strongly recommend it because its far more configurable than .NET ones.

Sample open-source usage:

http://imapclientlumisoft.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is that lumisoft still free? Can you give me the sample open-source for pop3 using lumisoft?

Comment: I don't have any samples because I changed companies and we don't do that here.